# Setting a delay on sending an email C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, razor-pages

I used the following tutorial to create a 'Contact Us' page on my ASP.NET Core Web Application:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-from-a-razor-page-in-net-core-2-using-system-net-mail/

And I was wondering if its possible to set a delay on the sending of the email?

This is my .cshtml for the page

```
@page
@model FarmersPortal.Pages.EmailRequestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('hero-range-1.jpg');
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<h2 style="color:white">Contact Us</h2>
<h5 style="color:white">If you have any issues with the site please fill out the form below and we will get back to you as soon as we can.</h5>
<h5 style="color:white">Please provide us with as much detail as possible.</h5>

<form asp-page="./EmailRequest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p style="color:white">
            From: <input type="text" asp-for="email.From" /><br />
            Subject: <input type="text" asp-for="email.Subject" /><br />
            Whats the Issue?: <textarea asp-for="email.Body"></textarea><br />
            <button asp-page-handler="SendEmail">Send Email</button>
        </p>
    </div>    
</form>
```

and the code behind (.cshtml.cs):

```
public class EmailRequestModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly filedbContext _context;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;

        public EmailRequestModel(filedbContext db, ApplicationDbContext dbcontext)
        {
            _dbcontext = dbcontext;
            _context = db;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public EmailMessage email { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }
        public async Task OnPostSendEmail()
        {
            using (var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("10.48.1.190"))
            {
                var emailMessage = new MailMessage();
                emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(email.From);
                emailMessage.To.Add("enter email here");
                emailMessage.Subject = email.Subject;
                emailMessage.Body = email.Body;

                await smtp.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
            }
        }

    }
```

If this question isn't allowed to be posted please let me know.

Comment: Please define "delay". Like seconds or days?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? If you delay sending for 5 minutes and it fails, how will you notify the user, who has probably left the page already. Sending an email to `email.From` saying "we didn't get your message", would be very strange.

Comment: You can use a scheduler like HangfireIO: https://www.hangfire.io/  or Quartz.NET: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: @Natrium Like 10 minutes? The purpose of my application is for admins to upload documents and then the user gets a notification saying they have a new document to view. So id like a 10 minute delay

Comment: You should use background task for sending emails. https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/running-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core then This task can be repeating task and from that you can send it after your 10 minutes will be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea of your question, I hope it can give you some help. Here is a simple demo :

I'm using `MediatR` to achieve it:

install `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` nuget package.

register it in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Create event class to pass data

```
//for testing, I just set username property in this event
    public record TestEvent(string Username): INotification
    {
    }
```

Create a event handler class

```
public class TestEventhandler : INotificationHandler<TestEvent>
    {
        public async Task Handle(TestEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //For testing, I delay 10 second here
           await Task.Delay(10000);
            //you can send email here
            Console.WriteLine($"Email send successfully, Username = {notification.Username}");
        }
    }
```

Then inject your MediatR into your controller (MVC) or PageModel(Razor Page)

```
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public HomeController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Person(string username)
        {
             //use this code to publish event
             _mediator.Publish(new TestEvent(username));
            //........other code.....
            return RedirectToAction("success");
        }
```

When user access specific action, It will publish the event. Here I am not use `await _mediator.Publish(new TestEvent(username));` to publish event, Because I don't want the user to be stuck on this Page until the mail is sent.

Demo:

[image]