# Issue about calling an async method without awaiting in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fire-and-forget

Here we have a requirement that in the ASP.NET Core Web API controller, a job should be created and executed in the background, and the controller should reply the response immediately once the job starts running. There will be another controller API which could query the execution status of the job but that is a different topic.

To be simpler, the code is similar to the following:

```cs
public class Job
{
  public async Task RunAsync()
  {
    //...
  }
}

// API Controller code
private Job _job;

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateJob()
{
    _job.RunAsync(); // <-- No awaiting, making the job running in the background
    await DoAnotherThingAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

I found that sometimes the running of this background job will be interrupted for some reasons - After this `CreateJob` API has returned, it looks like the `_job.RunAsync()` will not always completely finish its work - its execution thread could be killed at any time.

I know this is not a good implementation, but there are some questions:

1. Why could this background job execution be interrupted?
2. If I append `await` before `_job.RunAsync()`, this `CreateJob` API will eventually wait the background job to complete before it returns to the caller, which makes the job execution to be synchronous, right?
3. Except adopting third party frameworks like Quartz.NET and Hangfire, is there any simple solution to this issue?

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I think it's Easier to use third-party frameworks, You can also to consider using MediatR . Here is a similar situation in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729803/setting-a-delay-on-sending-an-email-c-sharp/74741016#74741016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found that sometimes the running of this background job will be interrupted for some reasons - After this CreateJob API has returned, it looks like the _job.RunAsync() will not always completely finish its work - its execution thread could be killed at any time.

Yup.

> Why could this background job execution be interrupted?

Any number of reasons! I explain several of them in [my blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html) (see the section "Shutdowns Are Normal"):

- Rolling updates.
- Applying OS or runtime patches.
- Periodic restarts built-in to ASP.NET/IIS.

In-memory work cannot survive application shutdown (and shutdowns are normal), so the only proper (reliable) solution is to store them somewhere durable (i.e., not in memory).

> If I append await before _job.RunAsync(), this CreateJob API will eventually wait the background job to complete before it returns to the caller, which makes the job execution to be synchronous, right?

Well, that depends on what you mean by "synchronous".

I would say that no, it's still asynchronous. With the `await`, the request thread is not blocked, so it's asynchronous.

But: ASP.NET will (asynchronously) wait until the job completes before returning the HTTP response.

Since ASP.NET doesn't return the HTTP response until the job is completed, then at a higher conceptual level you could say it was "synchronous".

> Except adopting third party frameworks like Quartz.NET and Hangfire, is there any simple solution to this issue?

No.

I have a [blog series on this subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) explaining *why* it's complex. Hangfire is about as simple of a solution as you're going to get.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, appreciate your comments! I think now I understand the issue and seems I have to refactor my current implementation.

Comment: Hi Stephen. The edit to the original post was a good one, and is widely supported here based on the preference for technical writing. I suspect the moderation ethic is that you can, if you wish, insist on chatty quoted material in your own post, but it will not reflect the edited question.

Comment: There is some interesting data on Meta Stack Overflow that suggests questions featuring chatty, needy, or begging language will attract more downvotes than ones that are succinct (I can find some links for you if that is of interest). Thus, modifying questions to [remove the fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin) does not only make them easier to parse for future readers - it protects low-rep users from downvotes they cannot afford.

Answer (score 0):

The first job interrupted because the method doesn't monitor it. The method returns exactly when second job finishes regardless the state of the first. You have to use synchronisation to ensure both jobs finished before leaving the method

```
var task1 = DoWorkAsync();
var task2 = DoMoreWorkAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, yes, I know that I should put the `await` before the method, but this will turn it into a synchronous execution which is not the requirement. Basically I want a fire-and-forget implementation that could execute the job in the background and making the POST API return immediately.

Comment: You have to use threading and not tasks then. Ensure a thread is always alive which is going to be a can of worms in a Web app where IIS or other host might kill it any time. I would start with adding a singleton service see if it can survive and run all the tasks there in a separate thread taking "job" from a queue.

Comment: P.S. Tbh you asked why it is aborted. I told you why. Your other requirements aren't the question here